# I've got HTTP::Response fail when connect plotly site with Perl API

Tags: perl, api, plotly

Recently, I've found plot.ly site and am trying to use it.
But, When I use Perl API, I can't success.
My steps are same below.

1. I sign up plot.ly with google account
2. Installed Perl module(WebService::Plotly)
3. Type basic example("https://plot.ly/api/perl/docs/line-scatter")

..skip..

```
use WebService::Plotly;
use v5.10;
use utf8;

my $user = "MYID";
my $key = "MYKEY";

my $py= WebService::Plotly->new( un => $user, key => $key );

say __LINE__; # first say

my $x0 = [1,2,3,4]; 
my $y0 = [10,15,13,17];
my $x1 = [2,3,4,5]; 
my $y1 = [16,5,11,9];

my $response = $py->plot($x0, $y0, $x1, $y1);
say __LINE__ ; # second say
```

..skip...

Then, Execute example perl code
=>> But, In this step, $py->plot always returned "HTTP::Response=HASH(0x7fd1a4236918)"
and second say is not exeucted
( I used Perl version 5.16.2 and 5.19.1, OS is MacOS X)

On the hands, python example("https://plot.ly/api/python/docs/line-scatter") is always succeed.

Please, let me know this problem.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Add this lines at the beginning of the script and show output 
`use Carp;
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
 confess @_;
};`

Comment: I've added your code into the beginning line of script. And I got result as  
12 and  
HTTP::Response=HASH(0x100e5e568)  What should I do more? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After fast look at source code of this module I can suggest to use it like in example below. Because any method may raise exception. On http error this will be HTTP::Response object

```
eval {
    my $response = $py->plot($x0, $y0, $x1, $y1);
};
if (my $err = $@) {
    if (!ref $err) {
        die "Plotly error: ", $err;
    }
    elsif ($err->isa('HTTP::Response')) {
        die "HTTP error: ", $err->status_line;
    }
    else {
        die "Unknown error: ", ref($err), " ($err)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to your kind advice, I could solve my problem.  reason is that LWP::Protocol::https isn't installed. I've never used eval function. I learned good tip from you. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at $py->content or any of the other attributes to the HTTP::Response object?

You have't told us anything other than that you've tried to print the value of an object reference, the output that you have provided from that, is the output one would expect.

Comment: You should select the correct response and mark it as such. The more "unanswered" questions you have, the less likely it will be for somebody to answer the next one.